# Preferred fix for auto-holster bug

Tags: mods, stalker-clear-sky

It's a well-known problem, especially in Garbage, that the auto-holstering system prevents one in some cases from occupying a faction home.

My researches tell me that installing the Sky Reclamation Project mod will fix this.

My question: is this the preferred fix? More specifically:

a) SRP comes with a lot of mods. I am not sure I want them all. Do I want them all but I'm just too noob to know?

b) Are there other "smaller" fixes? I see vague hints here and there, but no clear answers.

c) what is the downside to installing SRP? Having painfully discovered that mod installations invalidate saves, I am a mod skeptic.

Thanks,
GeePawHill

Comment: Preferred by who?  The community?  A specific person?

Comment: The question was aimed at the community, but the community is surely made up of the individual specific persons. I'd consider any answer at all a win.